# JTable not completely visible

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jsplitpane

I'm adding a two `JPanel` objects (panels contain tables) to a `JSplitPane`, for some reason the table is not completely visible. I wanted to add a screen shot for reference but stack overflow wouldn't allow me to do so :(. Anyway, the code related to this is as follows: Kindly suggest some solution.

```
 frame.setTitle(PAGE2);
          final String[] stream_column_names = { "IP Address", "Port", "IP Address", "Port", "Transport" };
          final String[] packet_column_names = { "#", "Direction", "Preview" };
          final JScrollPane pane1 = new JScrollPane();
          final JScrollPane pane2 = new JScrollPane();
          final JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
          final JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

          splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, streamPanel, packetPanel);
          splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
          splitPane.setDividerLocation(350);


          streamPanel = new JPanel();
          streamPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          pane1.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());  
          label1.setText("STREAM:");
label1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
          label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
          streamInfoTable = new JTable();        
          pane1.setViewportView(streamInfoTable);
          streamInfoTable.setModel(streamTableModel);
          streamTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(stream_column_names);

          streamPanel.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
          streamPanel.add(pane1);
          streamPanel.getPreferredSize();
          splitPane.add(streamPanel);

          packetPanel = new JPanel();
          packetPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          pane2.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());

          label2.setText("PACKET:");
          label2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
          label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

          packetInfoTable = new JTable();

          pane2.setViewportView(packetInfoTable);
          packetInfoTable.setModel(packetTableModel);
          packetInfoTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
          packetInfoTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
          packetTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(packet_column_names);

         packetPanel.add(label2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
          packetPanel.add(pane2);
          packetPanel.getPreferredSize();
          splitPane.add(packetPanel);

          centerPanel.add(splitPane);

          frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          frame.setVisible(true);

          jDesktopPane.add(frame);
```

Comment: Can you upload an image to an image sharing site and share with URL with us?

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem. The code you posted doesn't help.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a7jEidrqBgQjPDM_JRYB4BwMCZwB91wDMamA1gzjLdE/edit

Comment: Please post your [sscce](http://sscce.org) here to this site so we can all see your code without firewalls blocking our access.

Comment: i minimized it as much as I could. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: @codelearner: please read or re-read the [sscce link](http://sscce.org). You're missing an important part: code has to be compilable and runnable by us without our having to do anything to the code without our needing external data. Your code isn't even a class much less have a main method, etc... Again, this will take effort on your part, more than just deleting a few lines here and there, and again, if your problem is vexing it will be effort well spent.

Comment: Well, regardless, please do let us know if you solve this, and if so, what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Your centerPanel JPanel looks to be using its default layout which for JPanel is FlowLayout, a layout that does not resize the contents it displays and thus you risk possibly not showing the entire JScrollPane that holds your JTable.

Consider either giving your centerPanel a BorderLayout, or if it just holds the JSplitPane and nothing else, then getting rid of it all together and simply adding the JSplitPane to your frame's BorderLayout.CENTER position. Don't forget to call `pack()` on your JFrame before displaying it.

And again, if still stuck, then distill your problem down to an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and posting the latest code here.

Edit: not sure why you're giving your JScrollPane a layout as it's own default layout should work just fine.

Comment: frame.pack() is not solving the problem, the center panel holds a label and the table. I tried removing the center panel and adding the components directly it wouldn't give proper output.

Comment: @codelearner: then your best bet is to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). This is not your full GUI/program which few will want to see, but rather a minimal program that is populated with hard-coded data, that compiles, runs, demonstrates your problem but that does nothing else and has no code unrelated to your problem, also known as a minimal runnable example. Creating one of these will take effort, but if your problem is vexing, it will be effort well spent.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion about setting border layout for center panel. It worked :)